# Infinite scroll of images on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, optimization, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have to create an 'infinite' scroll of images let's say something similar to Facebook feed. I use a listbox that stores my entries, and for that I use the following code.

```
foreach (var newsPiece in feedDataArray){

StackPanel entry_holder = new StackPanel();
entry_holder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 28, 95, 166));
entry_holder.Width = 410;
entry_holder.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 20);
entry_holder.Tag = newsPiece.entryId;
TextBlock entry_title = new TextBlock();
Run titleFragment = new Run();
titleFragment.Text = newsPiece.posterName;
titleFragment.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

Run titleFragment2 = new Run();
titleFragment2.Text = " " + newsPiece.title;
titleFragment2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 155, 192, 231));

Run titleFragment3 = new Run();
titleFragment3.Text = newsPiece.withString;
titleFragment3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

Run titleFragment4 = new Run();
if (!(newsPiece.locationName == null))
{
    if (newsPiece.locationName.Length > 5) {
        titleFragment4.Text = " at " + newsPiece.locationName + ".";
    }

}
else {
    titleFragment4.Text = ".";
}

titleFragment4.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 155, 192, 231));

entry_title.Width = 395;
entry_title.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
entry_title.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
entry_title.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
entry_title.FontSize = 20;
entry_title.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Segoe WP Light");
entry_title.FontWeight = FontWeights.Light;
entry_title.Inlines.Add(titleFragment);
entry_title.Inlines.Add(titleFragment2);
entry_title.Inlines.Add(titleFragment3);
entry_title.Inlines.Add(titleFragment4);


entry_holder.Children.Add(entry_title);
Image entry_image;
BitmapImage tempBit;

    Uri imageURI = new Uri(newsPiece.imageURL);
    entry_image = new Image();
    entry_image.Width = 400;
    entry_image.Margin = new Thickness(5, 7, 7, 0);
    entry_image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
    tempBit = new BitmapImage(imageURI);
    tempBit.DecodePixelWidth = 400;
    entry_image.Source = tempBit;
    entry_holder.Children.Add(entry_image);

TextBlock entryFooter = new TextBlock();
entryFooter.Width = 300;
entryFooter.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
entryFooter.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
entryFooter.Text = newsPiece.likesNumber + " Likes " + newsPiece.commentsNumber + " Comments";
entryFooter.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 155, 192, 231));

TextBlock entryFooter2 = new TextBlock();
entryFooter2.Width = 170;
entryFooter2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
entryFooter2.Margin = new Thickness(10, -25, 5, 0);
string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
if (date == newsPiece.date)
{
    entryFooter2.Text = newsPiece.time;
}
else {
    entryFooter2.Text = newsPiece.date + " " + newsPiece.time;
}

entryFooter2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 155, 192, 231));
entryFooter2.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;



entry_holder.Children.Add(entryFooter);
entry_holder.Children.Add(entryFooter2);
feedEntries.Items.Add(entry_holder);}
```

Basically I insert a title an image and a date into a listbox item. The problem is that i have to load more newsPieces every time the user reaches the bottom of the list and I don't want to remove the items loaded earlier, but on low RAM devices such as Lumia 520, after I insert 20 items, it runs out of memory. Any idea for optimisation? Thank you.

You can ignore the text manipulation part of the code, the problem occurs only when I load images.
Loop:

```
Image entry_image;
BitmapImage tempBit;
Uri imageURI = new Uri(newsPiece.imageURL);
entry_image = new Image();
entry_image.Width = 400;
entry_image.Margin = new Thickness(5, 7, 7, 0);
entry_image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
tempBit = new BitmapImage(imageURI);
tempBit.DecodePixelWidth = 400;
entry_image.Source = tempBit;
entry_holder.Children.Add(entry_image);
```

Comment: I see a lot of UI handling in C# code, all that should be in XAML. You are adding likely-similar items into a container - you could achieve this way better via an MVVM implementation (use of XAML again). Also, try to use a different control for displaying the items - take a look at LongListSelector - it's intended for infinite scrolling. Ultimately, make sure to create a thumbnail of the actual image.

Comment: Thx for your reply @VasileMarianFălămaș, the problem is that my solution was designed for 7.1, I updated to 8 and It seems that longlistselector is still unavaliable

Comment: Mihai, LongListSelector is definitely available for Windows Phone 8 apps.  What do you mean when you say it is still unavailable?
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector#versionsTitleToggle)

Comment: @Patrick LongListSelector is part of Microsoft.Phone.Controls right? When I try to declare a new LongListSelector Visual Studio saids that I'm missing a reference.